# How to remove one column from datatable in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I have this code:

```
public ActionResult RcColdis() {
    string constr = @"Data Source=192.168.52.197,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=DB_ADRIAN;User ID=adrian;Password=password;";

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select a.secCode, b.[Haircut (%)],c.[Absolute IDR (Miliar)] from openquery(PDC_MYAPPS,'select secCode from mii.secReq')a left join (select * from RC_Saham)b on a.secCode=b.kode left join (select * from Absolute_IDR)c on b.kode=c.[Kode Saham]where b.[Haircut (%)] is not null union select a.code_Ic,a. PERC_HRCT, case  a. PERC_HRCT when 100 then 20 end from openquery(MANTARAY,'select b.code_ic, a.PERC_HRCT from cminstruments a, instrument_codes b where a.ID_CMI_CAPCO = b.INS_ID_INS_CAPCO')a left join (select * from Absolute_IDR)b on a.code_Ic = b.[Kode Saham]where code_Ic in (select a.secCode from openquery(PDC_MYAPPS,'select secCode from mii.secReq')a left join (select * from RC_Saham )b on a.secCode=b.kode left join (select * from Absolute_IDR)c on b.kode = c.[Kode Saham] where c.[Absolute IDR (Miliar)] is null )"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);

                    //Build the Text file data.
                    string txt = string.Empty;

                    //Add new line.
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                         foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                         {
                             //Add the Data rows.
                             txt += row[column.ColumnName].ToString() + "|";
                         }

                         //Add new line.
                         txt += "\r\n";
                    }

                    //Download the Text file.
                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.Buffer = true;
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=SqlExport.txt");
                    Response.Charset = "";
                    Response.ContentType = "application/text";
                    Response.Output.Write(txt);
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.End();
                }
           }
        }
    }  

    return View("Index");
}
```

It will export data from database to datatable and then txt file. I got the result which consist of from three columns:

```
asdas |2312|12312|
asdas |2312|12312|
sdgs  |2312|12312| 
assdfs|2312|12312|
assdfs|2312|12312|
```

I dont want to show second column in txt file. How can I do it? Thank you

Comment: Then don't select it in your query?

Comment: @Dion V I need to select it for reference to get data in third column.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe the best option in this case is to not select it at all in the first place.

You don't need to remove that column from the table if you just don't want to export the second column, you can use the `DataColumn.ColumnName` or `DataColumn.Ordinal`(index):

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
    {
        if (column.Ordinal != 1)
        {
            //Add the Data rows.
            txt += row[column.ColumnName].ToString() + "|";
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

However, if you want to remove it anyway:

```
dt.Columns.RemoveAt(1);
```

Comment: Great! it works. Thank you. Btw, how about if I want to add new column with all row value is 10 between two column above?

Comment: You're welcome. But i dont understand your new requirement. You want to add a new column with what values? Maybe you should ask another question.